# TranslateAnimation on TextView larger than the parent view Android

Tags: android, textview, marquee

I need an advice on `TranslateAnimation` on `TextView`

The TextView contain characters "STARTaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaEND" which is longer than the parent view

First 3 dots appear behind the TextView, therefore I set

```
BtmBar.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.MARQUEE);
```

Then i do some TranslateAnimation on the TextView but the TextView only show half of the characters like "STARTaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" while the "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaEND" is totally gone

Please look through the image for more graphical explanation

[http://i.imgur.com/FurAUqu.png](https://i.imgur.com/FurAUqu.png)

Below is the java code

```
BtmBar.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.MARQUEE);
        AnimationBtmBar = new TranslateAnimation(
                            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, +1f,
                            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, -1f,
                            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,
                            0f);
                    AnimationBtmBar.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
                    AnimationBtmBar.setDuration(5000);
                    AnimationBtmBar.setFillAfter(true);     
                    BtmBar.startAnimation(AnimationBtmBar);
```

Below is the XML code

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/BtmBar"
android:singleLine="true" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
android:textSize="25sp"
android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
android:text="@string/autoScrollingTextView"
android:clipChildren="false"
android:clipToPadding="false"/>
```

Any advices is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: add BtmBar.setSelected(true);

Answer (score 1):

### Very late answer. But I have the solution. It might help others.

Solution is to wrap `TextView` in `HorizontalScrollView`.
Don't forget to add `android:scrollbars="none"` to hide horizontal scroll bar.

Try the following:

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="none">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="SOME VERY LONG TEXT" />
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

And in your activity, add the following

```
Animation animationToLeft = new TranslateAnimation(
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, -1f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0f
);
animationToLeft.setDuration(12000);
animationToLeft.setRepeatMode(Animation.RESTART);
animationToLeft.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
title.setAnimation(animationToLeft);
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for Translate animation
use below code-

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/BtmBar"
android:singleLine="true" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
android:textSize="25sp"
android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
android:ellipsize="marquee"
android:singleLine="true"
android:text="@string/autoScrollingTextView"
android:clipChildren="false"
android:clipToPadding="false"/>
```

And add BtmBar.setSelected(true); in java

Comment: I tried this method before, the only problem is it will interact with the hardware keyboard (connected via USB), for example when i press DPAD_right, the textview will also move to right.

For your information i am doing some smart TV app which will use DPAD for navigation